# latest SQLite version errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite, nhibernate

Having just updated my SQLite dll via Nuget to v1.0.81.0, I am getting errors like the one below. This happens AFTER first executing successfully one or more times (not sure). The environment is vs2010 on an x64 machine but with build setting targeting x86.

I use SQLite to unit test my NHibernate mappings. Having frequently found SQLite a bit "cranky" in the past, I am reluctant to mess with a working unit test fixture (see below)

Anybody have a clue what is going wrong here?

Cheers,
Berryl

**Error Msg**

```
Unable to copy file "...\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll" to "bin\Debug\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll' because it is being used by another process. Parties.Data.Impl.NHib.Tests
```

**Unit Test Fixture (enough to show file access anyway)**

```
public abstract class SQLiteTestFixture
{

    protected override void BeforeAllTests()
    {
        _configureDbFile();
        base.BeforeAllTests();
    }

    protected override void AfterAllTests()
    {
        base.AfterAllTests();

        _deleteAllDbFiles();
    }

    #region Db File Maintenance

    /// <summary>
    /// Using a file is likely slower than just memory but not noticeably so far,
    /// AND seems to be a bit more stable
    /// </summary>
    private const string DB_FILE_SUFFIX = ".Test.db";

    /// <summary>
    /// Just make some random file name with a known suffix, so we can clean up when done.
    /// </summary>
    private void _configureDbFile()
    {
        _dbFile = Path.GetFullPath(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") + DB_FILE_SUFFIX);

        // highly unlikely but just in case the same file is already out there
        _deleteDbFile();
    }

    private void _deleteDbFile()
    {
        if (File.Exists(_dbFile)) File.Delete(_dbFile);
    }

    private static void _deleteAllDbFiles()
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "*" + DB_FILE_SUFFIX);
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            File.Delete(file);
        }
    }

    private string _dbFile;

    #endregion

}
```

}

Comment: this looks like a common Visual studio error where the host process of the debug version is still running after the execution which keeps the dll locked. Restarting VS solved this for me but it is annoying. Maybe someone has a solution for this

Comment: @Firo. Yes a restart clears up the problem but annoying is too kind of of a word to describe that! Have you got any recent links that explain the problem in detail? Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having this problem with SQLite 1.0.88.0 with VS2010 and TestDriven.Net.  I tried answers on several SO questions but the only thing that worked for me was this:

1. Tools -> Options -> TestDriven.Net -> General
2. Under *Run Test(s)*, Uncheck "Cache tests process between test runs"
3. Restart Visual Studio

You should now be able to run tests, debug tests, rebuild, etc. without having to restart processes or Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks @Berryl, since posting my answer I have still had a few issues with TestDriven.Net not letting go of a lock on the dll.  But for the most part this solution has been a huge time saver.

Answer (score 1):

KB article describing one possible cause

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313512/en-us

most of the following solve the problem temporarily

- restart Visual Studio
- http://aspadvice.com/blogs/ssmith/archive/2005/03/21/1849.aspx
- close casini webserver

Comment: I am pretty sure there is something about the lastest TestDriven.Net that doesn't play nicely with the lastest SQLite; I can kill the currently active tdd process and expect SQLite to work afterwards. Not great but better than a restart and likely an issue that will get sorted out. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Change the SQLLite dlls "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if newer" does the trick. (You migth need to restart VS after changing the property)

Comment: I'm using NuGet, I don't have references to DLLs

Comment: @miparnisari When using NuGet they are still listed under references where you can try having Copy Local = true, but that might be default. Do you see the dlls in the output folder?